# CheckAll CheckBox Jquery

Tags: jquery

I using this code to check the checkbox in a treeview.

*HTML:*

```
<div id="tree">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox"/> Root
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox"/> Child 1
                    <ul>
                        <li><input type="checkbox"/> Subchild 1</li>
                        <li><input type="checkbox"/> Subchild 2</li>
                        <li><input type="checkbox"/> Subchild 3</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox"/> Child 2
                    <ul>
                        <li><input type="checkbox"/> Subchild 1</li>
                        <li><input type="checkbox"/> Subchild 2</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>​
```

*JavaScript:*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tree input:checkbox").change(function() {
        var val = $(this).attr("checked");
        $(this).parent().find("input:checkbox").each(function() {
            if (val) {
                $(this).attr("checked", "checked");
            } else {
                $(this).removeAttr("checked");
            }
        });
    });
});​
```

*JSFiddle:* http://jsfiddle.net/jRAcq/

this works well. But if the any one of the sub node is unchecked then the root/child root to be unchecked. How can I do this one?

Comment: Should the root really be unchecked? I don't think so. 
It would imply that none of the child is unchecked.
If all of the child are unchecked then the root should be unchecked also. But not before. 
That's my 2 cents.

Comment: To clarify, if I click on Root, then click on Sub child 1, should Child 1 and Root be unchecked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#tree input:checkbox").change(function() {
    var val = $(this).attr("checked");
    $(this).parent().find("input:checkbox").each(function() {
        if (val) {
            $(this).attr("checked", "checked");
        } else {
            $(this).removeAttr("checked");
            $(this).parents('ul').each(function(){
                $(this).prev('input:checkbox').removeAttr("checked");
             });
        }
    });
});
```

});

Comment: @Priyank , that worked well, but if I uncheck any of the child checkbox then top most checkedbox remains checked :(

Comment: @Priyank Nice. That worked..How to implement to same in this one http://hamidseta.blogspot.in/2012/01/check-uncheck-all-checkbox-in-treeview.html

Answer (score 1):

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
                $.extend($.expr[':'], {
                    unchecked: function (obj) {
                        return ((obj.type == 'checkbox' || obj.type == 'radio') && !$(obj).is(':checked'));
                    }
                });

                $("#tree input:checkbox").live('change', function () {
                    $(this).next('ul').find('input:checkbox').prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));

                    for (var i = $('#tree').find('ul').length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                        $('#tree').find('ul:eq(' + i + ')').prev('input:checkbox').prop('checked', function () {
                            return $(this).next('ul').find('input:unchecked').length === 0 ? true : false;
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
```

for live demo see this link: http://jsfiddle.net/nanoquantumtech/JfMCP/

//Or

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.extend($.expr[':'], {
                unchecked: function (obj) {
                    return ((obj.type == 'checkbox' || obj.type == 'radio') && !$(obj).is(':checked'));
                }
            });

            jQuery.fn.reverse = [].reverse;

            $("#tree input:checkbox").live('change', function () {
                $(this).next('ul').find('input:checkbox').prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));

                $('#tree').find("input:checkbox + ul").reverse().each(function () {
                    $(this).prev('input:checkbox').prop('checked', $(this).find('input:unchecked').length === 0 ? true : false);
                });
            });
        });
```

//==================================================================================//

accroding to your html jquery code is below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $.extend($.expr[':'], {
                unchecked: function (obj) {
                    return ((obj.type == 'checkbox' || obj.type == 'radio') && !$(obj).is(':checked'));
                }
            });

            jQuery.fn.reverse = [].reverse;

            $('#PagesTree').find('input:checkbox').live('change', function () {
                $('#' + $(this).attr('name').replace(/CheckBox/g, '') + 'Nodes').find('input:checkbox').prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));

                $('#PagesTree').find('input:checkbox').reverse().each(function () {
                    var obj = $('#' + $(this).attr('name').replace(/CheckBox/g, '') + 'Nodes');
                    if (obj.find('input:checkbox').length > 0)
                        $(this).prop('checked', obj.find('input:unchecked').length === 0 ? true : false);
                });
            });
        });
```

for live demo see this link: http://jsfiddle.net/nanoquantumtech/GmT7U/

Comment: Demo works well, But this is not working in asp.net treeview. :(

Comment: can u show u r asp.net code and what version of jquery u r using?