# How to check/uncheck all asp.net checkbox on single checkbox event?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, checkbox

I have one checkbox name `Select All` on which I want to **check/uncheck** all my checkbox div wise.

As my checkboxes are asp.net controls that is `runat=server` so I am not getting how to handle it on client side.

This is my code:

```
<asp:CheckBox onchange="Checkallcheckbox()" ID="chkAll" runat="server" Text="Parent" /> -- parent of all checkboxes.

---------Section 1 -----------
<div id="section1">
    <li class="carousel-border">
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkParent1" runat="server" Text="Check All" /> --Parent of below 2 checkboxes
    </li>
    <li>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkchild1" runat="server" Text="Child 1" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkchild2" runat="server" Text="Child 2" />
    </li>                                
</div>

---------Section 2 -----------
<div id="section2">
    <li class="carousel-border">
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkParent2" runat="server" Text="Check all" /> --Parent of below 2 checkboxes
    </li>
    <li>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkchild3" runat="server" Text="Child 1" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkchild4" runat="server" Text="Child 2" />
    </li>                                
</div>

function Checkallcheckbox() {
    // How to check/uncheck all checkbox on this event
}
```

Comment: Give common class for check all checkbox and use it as `$('.checkAll').on('change', function() { $(this).closest('div').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);});`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CheckAll CheckBox Jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10736172/checkall-checkbox-jquery)

Comment: @Tushar:but what is i want to use control id instead of class then

Comment: @Learning use `$('[id^=chkParent]`).on('change', function`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ASP.NET (Webforms) when you use a server control like this:

```aspx
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkAll" runat="server" Text="Parent" />
```

It's rendered on the client like this:

```html
<span id="somprefix_chkAll">
  <input type="checkbox" />
</span>
```

So if you if you are using $("#<%= chkAll.ClientID %>") in your javascript then you really are waiting for the event of that span element (id="somprefix_chkAll") but the event never will be triggered since the **change** event is applied only for input elements ([see jQuery doc.](http://api.jquery.com/change/)).

But you can solve your problem easily, you can use a plain html control in asp.net and also it can be a server control (through the attribute: runat="server"), it means that you'll have access to the control in the code behind. For example, you can use this:

```aspx
<input type="checkbox" id="chkAll" runat="server" />
```

And in the code behind you can acces as always:

```csharp
//assigning:
this.chkAll.Checked = true;
//get:
var isChecked = this.chkAll.Checked;
```

Considering the above let me change your code:

```js
function Checkallcheckbox(currentClickedCheckbox) {

 var section1Chks= $('#section1').find(':checkbox');
 var section2Chks= $('#section2').find(':checkbox');
 
 if($(currentClickedCheckbox).is(':checked')) {
  section1Chks.prop('checked', true);
  section2Chks.prop('checked', true);
 } else {
  section1Chks.prop('checked', false);
  section2Chks.prop('checked', false);
 }
}

function CheckAllInSection(currentClickedCheckbox) {
 var $currentChk = $(currentClickedCheckbox);
 var sectionChks= $currentChk.closest('div').find(':checkbox');
 var checkAll = $currentChk.is(':checked');
  sectionChks.prop('checked', checkAll);

}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="chkAll" onchange="Checkallcheckbox(this)"   runat="server" value="Parent" />
<br />
---------Section 1 -----------
<div id="section1">
    <li class="carousel-border">
 <input type="checkbox" id="chkParent1" runat="server" onchange="CheckAllInSection(this)" value="Check All" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="chkchild1" runat="server" value="Child 1" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="chkchild2" runat="server" value="Child 2" />
    </li>                                
</div>

---------Section 2 -----------
<div id="section2">
    <li class="carousel-border">
        <input type="checkbox" id="chkParent2" runat="server" onchange="CheckAllInSection(this)" value="Check All" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="chkchild3" runat="server" value="Child 3" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="chkchild4" runat="server" value="Child 4" />
    </li>                                
</div>
```

See the [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n08645j1/1/).

Comment: your explaination is superb and 100% correct but you havent done anything on parent checkbox selection(for section1 chkparent1 and section 2 chkparent2)

Comment: setting input type=checkbox and runat=server so everything would be same right on server side?

Comment: Yes, in most cases. See in the MSDN: "CheckBox Web Server Control" and "HtmlInputCheckBox Server Control".

Comment: just wanted to ask you 1 thing that how to uncheck this all checkbox on page load that is through property or in document.ready?

Comment: through property in code behind: chk1.Checked=false; chk2.Checked = false; an so on... In document ready with this line: var chks = $("form").find(':checkbox'); chks.prop('checked', false);

Comment: Thanks alot for your ans.i hope you would have given this answer yesterday

Answer (score 2):

Give them corresponding class names to make it possible to select them.
Then, you will be able to do this with a single selector:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkAll" runat="server" Text="Parent" />

<div id="section1" class="section">
    <li class="carousel-border">
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkParent1" Class="chkParent" runat="server" Text="Check All" /> --Parent of below 2 checkboxes
    </li>
    <li>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkchild1" Class="chkChild" runat="server" Text="Child 1" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkchild2" Class="chkChild" runat="server" Text="Child 2" />
    </li>                                
</div>

<div id="section2" class="section">
    <li class="carousel-border">
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkParent2" Class="chkParent" runat="server" Text="Check all" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkchild3" Class="chkChild" runat="server" Text="Child 1" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkchild4" Class="chkChild" runat="server" Text="Child 2" />
    </li>                                
</div>
```

Now, in your JS you can attach `change` handlers:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $chkAll = $("#<%= chkAll.ClientID %>");

    $chkAll.change(function() {
        $(".chkParent, .chkChild").prop('checked', this.checked);
    });

    $(".chkParent").change(function() {
        $(this).closest('.section').find('.chkChild').prop('checked', this.checked);
    });
});
```

You may also want to add the following handler:

```
  $(".chkChild, .chkParent").change(function() {
      var allCheckedInGroup =  $(this).closest('.section').find('.chkChild:not(:checked)').length === 0;
      $(this).closest('.section').find('.chkParent').prop('checked', allCheckedInGroup);

      var allChecked = $(".chkParent:not(:checked)").length === 0;
      $chkAll.prop('checked', allChecked);
  });
```

in order to make changes reflect into "Select All" checkboxes. Try to click something and will understand it.

Here is the working [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ykurmangaliyev/unr5xp8p/) (without ASP.NET).

Comment: you cant use  $("#chkAll") this like because its not a html control.its an asp.net control.so this event wont fire like this

Comment: @Learning Oh, you are right. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer.It worked but i am getting one problem so could you please help me

Comment: take care. asp:CheckBox is rendered as a span with a checkbox inside so chkAll will be part of the span element. But yo can use <input type=checkbox" runat="server" id="chkAll" ...

Comment: @AiApaec:I am unable to fire chkall event due to 1 issue.so can you please help me with that.

Comment: Yeldar, [join chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97581/room-for-learning-and-tushar)